# Why is SignalR getting a 404 on the negotiate call in my Angular web app?

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, signalr

I am attempting to initialize SignalR in my Angular 6 app and calling into a separate ASP.Net webapi for the hubs.

CORS is set up correctly and allowing the calls through, however, I am now stuck on this error:

```
Debug: Sending negotiation request: http://devapi.mywebapi.com/srtest/negotiate
http://devapi.mywebapi.com/srtest/negotiate 404 (Not Found)
```

I have installed 1.0 of the @aspnet/signalr typescript NPM library and I am initializing it like so:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { HubConnection, HubConnectionBuilder, LogLevel } from '@aspnet/signalr';

@Component({
    selector: "test",
    templateUrl: "test.component.html"
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    private hubConnection: HubConnection;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("http://devapi.mywebapi.com/srtest")
            .configureLogging(LogLevel.Debug)
            .build();

        this.hubConnection
            .start()
            .then(() => console.log('Connection started!'))
            .catch(err => console.log('Error while establishing connection :('));
    }
}
```

I have my Startup class defined as:

```
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Api.Controllers.SignalR.Startup))]
namespace Api.Controllers.SignalR
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

and my hub class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Api.Controllers.SignalR
{
    public class SRTestHub : Hub
    {
        public void SendTest(string message)
        {
            var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SRTestHub>();
            context.Clients.All.receiveMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Based on my understanding of SignalR, this is not how it works...do you have some resource that your are using as a guideline?

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems:

**1. Inside a hub you allready have the clients property**

You inherit the "Clients" Property from Hub class.
The following is enough:

```
public class SRTestHub : Hub
    {
        public void SendTest(string message)
        {
            Clients.All.receiveMessage(message);
        }
    }
```

**2. Url of connection does not match**

Also in the server part you should configure something that the url matches. How the server should know that the hub is running on "http://devapi.mywebapi.com/srtest"?

**3. It looks like you are mixing signalR core and "old" signalr.**

Client and server must have same versions.

I suggest you to read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client

In the case you are using signalr core read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-2.1